transactional lambda in aws dynamodb to generate a counter of new records from one table to another table?
In dynamodb I have a "votes" table that records a unique email, and only one option (out of 10 possible), in the hypothetical case that more than 1000 votes are made per second, I could execute a lambda that is activated every 25 new records and accumulate the number of votes (option) received in another table "election" that contains 10 elements (the options) and a value attribute that would be the accumulator? The question is how I do a writing concurrency control so that votes are not lost. Would transactional writing prevent this for this many votes per second?
The tables would be on-demand.
thanks!
Do not carry out tests for cost reasons before trying it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Every key in DynamoDB can provide you 1000 WCU. Since you refer to your key as a unique email, I find it highly unlikely a single user will vote more than 1000 times per second.
UpdateItem in DynamoDB is atomic, and strongly serialized. This means that you will not lose updates based on concurrency, all updates will succeed to matter how high the concurrency so long as it's not more than 1000 per second to induce throttling.

Thank you very much for the response, to clarify, each vote would be from one user, that is, 1000 votes = 1000 different users.
The idea is to avoid a scan of the "votes" table and accumulate the number of votes in the "election" table to see the total vote in "real time"

Typically how you do this is to use a Lambda with a tumbling window. For example, aggregate the metrics every 1 minute. What you dont want to do is update the items in the "votes" table at the same rate as votes are coming in, as you would induce a hot key if a candidate had more than 1000 votes per second.

This is a textbook preaggregation. Write your votes into an append-only table and use Dynamo streams (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html) to update pre-aggregated stats in a different table. Make sure you track timestamp and pk of the last processed event in case the process needs to be restarted.
